# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$ using Fourier series method.

Tags: fourier-analysis, binomial-coefficients, fourier-series

I'm trying to prove the binomial identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}.$$
This is a problem from "Fourier Series and Integrals" by Mckean.

---

So far, I have computed sums of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s},$ where $s$ is a positive even number. The trick then was to find a Fourier Series such that The Fourier coefficients were of the form $a\cdot n^{-s/2}$ where $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Lastly, I applied Plancherels identity to finish the computation.

However in this case, I do not see how to follow this method. They give me a hint in the exercise:

$\text{ }$

$\Big[$ **Hint:** $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} e_k=(1+e_1)^n$; also look at $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}e_{k-n}=2^{2n}\cos^{2n}\pi x$ $\Big ]$.

$\text{ }$

Right now, I am trying to figure out why we consider the summations in the hint and what the connection is between the Hint and the problem I want to solve.

Should I think of $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} e_k$ as the Fourier series expansion of $f=(1+e_1)^n$? If this is the case, Plancherels identity tells me that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(k)|^2=||f||_{L^2}^2.$$ 
Furthermore,
$$\hat{f}(k)={n\choose k}.$$
And thus we have the left hand side in the Binomial identity (except that it starts from $k=0$ but in Plancherels identity we start from $k=1$?).

Lastly, I just 'hope' that $||f||_{L^2}^2=2^{2n}\cos^{2n}\pi x$? Then
$$||f||_{L^2}^2=\int_{S^1} |(1+e_1)^n|^2 dn=\int_{S^1} |(1+e_1)|^{2n} dn=\cdots$$

Perhaps I should integrate the above over $x$ instead of $n$, since $e_1=e^{2\pi i x}$? I am pretty confused right now since there are quite a few variables to keep track on.

---

Is this a good approach or should I do something different? Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, $e_k=e^{2\pi i k x}$ :)

Comment: Yes, you can write the integral as $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |(1+e_1)^n|^2 dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |1+e_1|^{2n} dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}2^{2n}\cos^{2n} \pi x\,dx = \dots$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I do hope you noticed that this is just the issue of the equality of the coefficient of $x^y^n$ in the expansions of $((x+y)^n)^2=(x+y)^{2n}$? Somewhat more elementary than a proof via Plancherel and so on, I think.